# Neopixel WS2812B signal noise

Tags: arduino, led, esp8266, led-strip, ws2812b

I made a stair led with 610 leds.
All powered with a ATX psu.
The PSU can`t deliver the 5v for the led stripe so im using for 300 of them a buck driver and for the rest the 5v ATX out.
The Buck is powered over the atx.
Power injection over 4mm2 cable every 1.5m (every stair)

I am using a esp 01 with esp home in junction with home assistant.
For the control of the leds im using this eps led schield:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000089372031.html

**The problem is now happening when all of the leds are transitioning in animations. they signal gets corrupted. And i get random flickering while transitions happen.** And only while the animations happen. Any idea how to fix it?????

i tried:

- soldering the last pin in the row (big nono)
- capacitors on the ATX and Buck driver. Nope no change
- all grounds are connected
- When i try to add the recommended resistor on the beg of the stripe it gets worse...

I am guessing the data lane gets much induction interference when the 600 leds change current draw... When i use the scan animation where you only have like 100 leds on it does not happen.

problem is how to remedy this????

Here the esp home yaml:

```
power_supply:
  - id: 'led_power_supply'
    pin:
      number: 0
      inverted: true
  
light:
   - platform: fastled_clockless
     power_supply: led_power_supply
     chipset: WS2812B
     pin: 2
     num_leds: 608
     name: stepenice RGB
     id: sve_stepenice
     rgb_order: GRB
     max_refresh_rate: 2.5ms
     default_transition_length: 1s
     effects:  
      - random:
          name: Random Color
          transition_length: 4s
          update_interval: 5s
      - addressable_scan:
          name: Scan Effect
          move_interval: 50ms
          scan_width: 32
      - addressable_twinkle:
          name: Twinkle Effect  
          twinkle_probability: 70%
          progress_interval: 8ms
      - addressable_fireworks:
          name: Fireworks Effect
          update_interval: 60ms
          spark_probability: 80%
          use_random_color: true
          fade_out_rate: 130
      - flicker:
          name: Flicker 
          alpha: 95%
          intensity: 30% 
      - addressable_rainbow:
          name: Rainbow 
          speed: 60
          width: 300
```

Comment: You should start by finding out what the problem is. It could be interference, but it could just as well be power supply issues, overloaded digital pins, loose connections, defective parts, etc. etc.

Comment: I see you have already sorted out the Neopixel urban legends: resistor on data line, connecting the the data line at the end. Good. But how do you know the signal is corrupted? Did you look at it with a DSO? I very much doubt it.

Comment: With Neopixels, it usually boils down to two issues: power supply and software. Software issues is more likely. If the microcontroller is somehow interrupted, the new color values are not shifted in all the way and incorrect colors are displayed for a few milliseconds. This appears like flickering. If you had a loose connection, it would work up to a certain point and only affect LEDs after that point. Even for power supply issues, it would likely not affect those close to the power supply unless the ESP8266 is affected.

Comment: Can you try to switch from *fastled_clockless* to * neopixelbus*? FastLED is know to have problems if interrupts occur (or to prevent other libraries from working properly if they require interrupts). Neopixelbus uses DMA transfers not affected by interrupts.

Comment: Hmmm neopixel bus certanly did help :) But i still get ocasional animation errors. BUT muuuuuuuuuch lesss. Could it be that the pixels are taking to much current while animating depriving the esp??? could a cap near it help? hmmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that I added a small ceramic capacitor on every stair between + and - and a 100 uF one so I prevented the extreme currents.
That solved the noise.